# file pattern matching variables with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to figure out this file pattern. I have the following code:

```
def file_pattern_match(self, fundCode, startDate, endDate):

    # check if the fundcode is in the array or if the fundcode matches one in the array
    fundCode = fundCode if fundCode in self.fundCodes else 'Invalid_Fund_Code'

    # set a file pattern
    file_pattern = 'unmapped_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv'.format(fund=fundCode, start=startDate, end=endDate) 

    # look in the unmappedDir and see if there's a file with that name

    # if the there is load the positions
    pass
```

This is a funciton that's part of a class. There's one issue. I just realized that the parameter `fundCode` will actually be an array of values, so I need to use some sort of delimiter. In the end, I want to look for files matching this kind of pattern:

`unmapped_FUND1_FUND2_FUNDETC_20180203_20180204.CSV` or

`unmapped_FUND1_20180203_20180204.CSV`

I'm guessing regex would be a good use for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try `join`.

```
fundCode_raw = ['FUND1','FUND2','FUNDETC']
fundCode_str = '_'.join(fundCode_raw)

>> fundCode_str
'FUND1_FUND2_FUNDETC'
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need regex just to see if a file with that name exists. You can just construct the name of the file you're looking for (with the appropriate path), and then test to see if it exists.

```
import os
path = "unmappedDir/unmapped_{fund}_{start}_{end}.csv".format(fund = "_".join(fundCode), start = startDate, end = endDate)
if os.path.isfile(path):
    # Do loading.
```